# In Ember, how can I access the custom inflector defined in my initializers?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm defining custom inflector rules in `app/initializers/custom-inflector-rules` like so:

```
// app/initializers/custom-inflector-rules

import Inflector from 'ember-inflector';

export function initialize(/* application */) {
  const inflector = Inflector.inflector;

  // Tell the inflector that the plural of "campus" is "campuses"
  inflector.irregular('campus', 'campuses');
}

export default {
  name: 'custom-inflector-rules',
  initialize
};
```

How can I access my initialized inflector with these custom rules within my application?

For example, in a serializer file, I want to be able to call `pluralize` like so:

```
import ??? as Inflector from ???

Inflector.inflector.pluralize("campus"); // campuses
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the import already from your initializer:

```
import Inflector from 'ember-inflector';
```

Then you can just do `Inflector.inflector.pluralize('...')`.

You can also just directly import `pluralize` for the default inflector:

```
import { singularize, pluralize } from 'ember-inflector';
pluralize('...');
```

This is exactly `Inflector.inflector.pluralize` as you can [see in the source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inflector/blob/master/addon/lib/system/string.js)

There is even a handlebars helper:

```
{{pluralize "taco"}}
```

The complete docs are in [the github readme](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inflector).